# Teleric Grid returns 500 Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

Hello I am working on returning partial view to div using ajax in asp.net mvc3. This view contains teleric grid

this is my view code

```
 <input type="text" style="width: 320px;border: 1px solid rgb(177, 177, 177);" id="OrderIdToImport" onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13);" />
  <input type="button" class="t-button" value="Import" name="Add" id="ImportProducts" onclick="ImportProductsFromOrder();" /> 
        <div id="ImportedProducts">

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function ImportProductsFromOrder() {
                var OrderID = $('#OrderIdToImport').attr('value');

                if(OrderID=="")
                {
                alert('Please Specify OrderID');
                }

                     $.ajax({
                            cache:true,
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "@(Url.Action("ImportProducts", "Order"))",
                            data: "orderId=" + OrderID ,
                            success: function (data) {

                            $("#ImportedProducts").html(data);
                             return false;                    
                                             },
                            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                                                      //alert('Failed to subscribe.');
                                              }, 
                            complete: function() {   } 

                           }); // end ajax code

                     return false;
            }
</script>
```

Following is my Controller actions

```
  public ActionResult ImportProducts(int orderId)
        {

            var model = new ImportedProductsModel();
            model.Id = orderId;
            var order = _orderService.GetOrderById(model.Id);

            return PartialView("ImportProducts", model);
        }



[GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
        public ActionResult ImportedProductsInGrid(GridCommand command, ImportedProductsModel model)
        {
            var order = _orderService.GetOrderById(model.Id);

            var orderProductvariants = order.OrderProductVariants.Where(o => !o.Deleted);

            var gridModel = new GridModel<ImportedProductsModel>
            {
                Data = orderProductvariants.Select(x =>
                {
                    return new ImportedProductsModel()
                    {
                        Id = x.Id,
                        Name = x.ProductVariant.Product.Name,
                        Quantity = x.Quantity,
                        UnitPriceExclTax = x.UnitPriceExclTax,
                        TaxRate = x.UnitPriceExclTax / (x.UnitPriceExclTax - x.UnitPriceExclTax),
                        UnitPriceInclTax = x.UnitPriceInclTax,
                        MRP = x.OldPrice,
                        UnitCost = x.UnitCost
                    };
                }),
                Total = orderProductvariants.Count()
            };
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = gridModel
            };
            // return PartialView("SearchProduct", model.ProductSearchResult);
        }
```

My partial view is as follows

```
@model ImportedProductsModel

@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{


     <p>
    </p>
    <table class="adminContent">
        <tr>
            <td>
                @(Html.Telerik().Grid<ImportedProductsModel>()
                        .Name("importedproducts-grid")
                .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("onDataBinding"))
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(x => x.Id);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.Name);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.Quantity);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.UnitPriceExclTax);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.TaxRate);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.UnitPriceInclTax);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.MRP);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.UnitCost);
                        })
                        .Pageable(settings => settings.PageSize(40).Position(GridPagerPosition.Both))
                        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("ImportedProductsInGrid", "Order", Model))
                        .EnableCustomBinding(true))
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onDataBinding(e) {
//alert('Hi');

        }
   </script>

}
```

I am returing requested url returned 500  Error

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

try...
...

```
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("ImportProducts", "Order", Model))
```

....

```
[GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
public ActionResult ImportProducts(GridCommand command, ImportedProductsModel model)
        {
    ....

 return View(new GridModel(gridModel));
}
```

Comment: Best overloaded methods has invalid arguments, GridModel takes table as argument